# How do I bind to both public IP and localhost with AppHostHttpListenerBase

Tags: servicestack

I have created a ServiceStack Windows service which runs an `AppHostHttpListenerBase`. I can get it to listen for remote requests by listening on the private IP address of the server (e.g. `http://1.2.3.4:8080/`.  In such cases, I can consume the services across the Internet using the server's public IP address, but requests executed on the server to `http://localhost:8080/` fail.

If I change the binding address to `http://*:8080/`, then requests to `localhost` succeed, but I can no longer access the server across the Internet; I get a 503 Service Unavailable.

Any ideas how I can have my web services listen to both local requests and requests across the Internet?

And, just as importantly, why is it that when **loosening** the restriction on the listening address from a specific IP to a `*` do requests across the Internet suddenly start to fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that some other listener is already handling the request, and the * only matches those not handled. I would just try to listen to `http://+:8080/` in the hope that it helps.
For further information on HttpListenerPrefix see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerprefixcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Great, that got it. I had a previous URL reservation for the specific IP address configured with `netsh http add urlacl`. Once I actually removed the old reservation, the * version started working too. Thanks!